# access values from a associative array only using there array index number

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

First I have this associative array

```
$players = array("group1" => array("player1" => "Kevin Durant", "player2" => "Kyrie Irving"), "group2" => array("player1" => "Demian Lillard", "player2" => "Derrick Rose"));
```

I know I can just use this way of looping

```
//create an empty array to be used as a container for our looped array
$data_arrays = array();
foreach($players as $data=>$key):
    array_push($data_arrays,$key['player1'],$key['player2']);
endforeach;
```

but what I want is get there value base on there array index, e.g.

```
foreach($players as $data=>$key):
    array_push($data_arrays,$key[0],$key[1]);
endforeach;
```

but unfortunately and sadly, it returms me an error,

> Undefined offset: 0

any help, clues, suggestions, recommendations, ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
foreach($players as $data=>$key):
    $groupPlayers = array_values( $key );
    array_push($data_arrays,$groupPlayers[0],$groupPlayers[1]);
endforeach;
```

As a side note: your use of the variable names `$data` and `$key` is rather unorthodox: the key is the index of an array element, data is usually considered the value of the array element. So I would suggest to switch them, i.e.:

```
foreach($players as $key=>$data):
    $groupPlayers = array_values( $data );
    array_push($data_arrays,$groupPlayers[0],$groupPlayers[1]);
endforeach;
```

Comment: cool, how about if I'm going to get the name of the array object, e.g. I want to get the name of $players[0] which is 'player1', any ideas how to do that please?

Comment: @CodeDemon For that you could simply use the value of the `$key` variable that's already defined (in my second example, that is). Else you could use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys), in the same way I demonstrated the use of `array_values()`.

Comment: As a side note: If you have numeric indices, `array_values()` will ignore them and index your array based on the `foreach()` ordering.

Comment: @CodeDemon Sorry, the first statement in my reply comment was not correct, of course. `$key` will hold "group1", etc. (the key value of the outer array), not "player1", etc.

Comment: @CodeDemon Another sloppy thing of me is that you should choose another variable name than `$players` inside the `foreach` loop; otherwise it will overwrite the original `$players` array. Sorry about that; I'll correct this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
<?php
$players = array("group1" => array("player1" => "Kevin Durant", "player2" => "Kyrie Irving"), "group2" => array("player1" => "Demian Lillard", "player2" => "Derrick Rose"));

$data_arrays = array();
foreach($players as $data => $key):
    $data_arrays = array_merge($data_arrays, array_values($key));
endforeach;

print_r($data_arrays);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5133c3f317beccc5c2b0bbd56770359a1040c37

An Alternative, shorter way to do it using array_reduce:

```
$players = array("group1" => array("player1" => "Kevin Durant", "player2" => "Kyrie Irving"), "group2" => array("player1" => "Demian Lillard", "player2" => "Derrick Rose"));

$players = array_reduce($players, function(&$players, $v) {return array_merge(array_values($players), array_values($v));}, array());

print_r($players);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92c51ac92fdfde40df3e4fc9d469d52d19f05376